# terminal x clipboard 0~ prepended 1~ added

Tags: command-line, clipboard

With the X clipboard, I often have `0~` prepended and `1~` added to it.
That seems to happen often in gnome-terminal.

So in a terminal, let's say I highlight `abc`, then when I middle click, it will become `0~abc1~`. Issuing a reset solves the problem, but it tends to come back rather quickly again, and seems much more frequent since 16.04 somehow.

Any pointer greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This problem seems to be due to "bracketed paste mode". 
A fix is to issue a `printf "\e[?2004l"` (I put an alias for it). More information on [Arch forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=174595).